# How to pass 2d array in http post request of angular 2

Tags: angular

everyone

i have searched but not found the way how to pass 2d array in http post request.
 i want to sent 2d array in body of http reqeust.

**Here is code**

```
 let body = JSON.stringify({outlets_attribute[][name]: outlet});<--- giving syntax error here

return this.http.post('URL',body ,{headers:  this.Get_Header()});
```

if someone know, please guide how to handle this.
Thanks!

Comment: `this.http.post(url, the2dArray);`? Given that what you have is syntactically incorrect, it's hard to understand what you want to achieve with that made up syntax.

Comment: i want to send {outlets_attribute[][name]: outlet} this in my http post request but don't know the proper method for doing that....

Comment: The problem is that this is completely invalid JavaScript. So I don't understand what you actually want to do. An object has keys which are strings, and values which are anything. You're trying to use `outlets_attribute[][name]` as key, which is not a valid attribute name, and outlet as value. Moreover, I have no idea of what these variables are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLSearchParams:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

with something like:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('array[]', 'val1');
    params.append('array[]', 'val2');
return this.http.post('/endpoint', params).map(
      (response) => response
    )
```